# creating a query within a query

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am using a filtering system to categorize products. The filters display with the  product results, and are static links, for users to narrow down their choices.

I managed to show all the filters within one query. However, I really would like to add a numbering system for each filter. i.e. a number after each filter, that says how many results will be shown if said filter is selected, or removed.

- pants (21)
- shirts (17)
- t-shirts (34)

Like that

My filters query is

```
$qry = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
```

But then what I want to achieve is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry) {
     $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
     $qry1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category=$cat_id");
     $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($qry1);
     $filter[$cat_id] = array('cat_name'=>$row['cat_name'],'results'=>$num_results);
}
```

So I am trying to achieve the above with just one query, or even 2 if necessary, but not 30 (as there are 30 filters, i.e. one query for each filter would not be efficient)

Is there something along the lines of

```
$qry = mysqli_query("SELECT *,count(SELECT * FROM products WHERE category=cat_id) FROM categories");
```

I know its a bizare query, but I mean is there some what of counting the results of another query in one query?

Comment: you never executed the query for one thing

Comment: I wanted to create an array with the cat_name and num_results

Comment: ok can i use PDO in my answer  ? i hate mysqli , if thats ok

Comment: I'd prefer mysqli, I am not that familiar with PDO, but if the queries are the same, I guess it should be fine.

Comment: another Q , do you want to show all the fields in the products table ? or just the name of the catalog and the number of that catalog ?

Comment: I have a separate query for the products, but if I can do it all in one query then that would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your category name column is named category_name  you could use  a count and a group by on join

```
SELECT  a.category_name , count(*)
FROM  category as a
inner join products as b  on b.category =a.cat_id
group by a.category_name
```

Comment: Wow, I was hoping for something like that, its going to take me a lot of reworking, but if it works, then you are amazing, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what i understand is that you want beside every catalog name you have the number of the results for that catalog .Here is what i think that may help you : 
What you should use is `Group By` function in your query , like this :

```
$qry = mysqli_query("SELECT *  , COUNT( id ) As ProductNumber FROM products GROUP BY category);
```

the `id` field is the primary key in the table that i have in my DB , change it with the one that you have .

More about Group by here : [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Let me know if this one helped you , or if you need help in putting it in yours . 
Note : Did not used PDO .